# awk print with decimal integer and floating point in bash

Tags: awk

I want to print 1.7 to 001.70 in awk. it tried this command:

`echo 1.7 | awk '{ printf("%03d.1f\n", $1) }'`

but its output is instead `001.1f`.

Comment: Take out the `d`. This is all an `f`-type format string. You don't mix `d` and `f` strings for integer and floating-point parts; when you're printing a floating-point value that's larger than 1, it's all one floating-point value.

Comment: It should be `%06.2f` to get the output you want.

Comment: `%06` means the entire field is 6 characters with leading zeroes. `.2` means 2 digits after the decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo 1.7 | awk '{ printf("%06.2f\n", $1) }'
```

This breaks down as:

- `%f` = format a floating point value
- `06` = 6 character field padded with leading zeroes
- `.2` = 2 digits after the decimal point